# Using developer tools on my website and the amount of code that it is showing

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

I have a general non-code related question about my website. When I used developer tools to look at html code on website, I saw all of the code. I have used developers tools on other websites and it only shows all of the class names for each section of the website and the CSS. How can I limit how much a user can see of my code when using something like developer tools? It's not that I don't want developers to look at how my website works, but there should be a limit to how much they can see, since it is not copyrighted.

Comment: Once it is in their browser you can't stop them from doing whatever they want with it including viewing it all.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I change that for the future

Comment: There is no limit to what they can see. You can try to be sneaky about it but ultimately once it hits their browser it's there to be viewed.

Comment: Yeah I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any one of a variety of code minifiers/obfuscators to reduce the visibility of the code. But you can't prevent people from seeing the content, which is why you'll want to keep certain values, such as authentication keys, on your server.

Comment: I dont want to prevent people from seeing the content just reduce the visibility as you said. I believe that code should be free and anyone can view it, but there is a limit when it comes to certain things.